# dominated convergence theorem application (finding the dominating function)

Tags: measure-theory

what is the the integrable function $g$ over nonnegative real that dominates $(n-x)^n$? I was thinking using some sort of triangle ineq to get the function $g$. However, if i do this, $g$ is dependent of $n$ also, which is something that i do not want to happen.

Comment: Integrable...dominated... **where**?

Comment: nonnegative real

Comment: ? You mean the ray $\;[0,\infty)\;$ ? With Lebesgue, Borel (the same here) measure...?

Comment: Well, $(n-x)^n$ isn't integrable over the non-negative reals for any $n$, and furthermore $\{(n-x)^n\}$ diverges pointwise for all $x \in [0, \infty)$, so I'm fairly certain that there is no function that dominates all $(n-x)^n$.

Comment: okay, coz, I was thinking of using dominated convergence to compute the integral of $(n-x)^n$ over the non negative reals